# Why Does Not My Program Works ???Float Casting

Tags: casting, floating-point, double

Nothing is printed as output but when i write while(x==3.1f) it works.
i have thoroughly searched for an answer and i even find some but it is not really helping me. people have answered that using f as suffix make it float point default type is double. But how does it really works.. i want someone to explain me at the beginner level . I Have just started to learn C programming Language. Please Don't mark this question as answered before because i have already read all those answer and i am still not able to convince myself.
I also want to know what does suffix f exactly do .. and how does a decimal is stored in binary . Why does not we simple give . as a another binary code and proceed as same as we did for integers . I may be asking something stupid . But i  am really confused

```
include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   float x = 3.1 ;
while(x==3.1)
{
printf("%f\n",x);
x=x-0.1;


}

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`3.1`, in a C program, means the closest `double` to the decimal fraction 3.1. Assuming IEEE 754 binary floating point, the commonest implementation, its exact value is 3.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625

When you assign it to `x`, it is converted to the closest `float`, 3.099999904632568359375.

Comparisons between a `float` and a `double` are done by converting the `float` to `double` and comparing doubles.

All conversions from `float` to `double` are exact, so the `while` condition would be true only if 3.099999904632568359375 were equal to 3.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625

The exactness of `float` to `double` conversion is not just a matter of `double` taking up more space than `float`. An IEEE binary floating point number has three fields, a sign bit, a power-of-two exponent, and a significand. The `float` exponent and significand ranges are proper subsets of the corresponding double ranges.

On the wider questions, `float` and `double` are extremely compact and efficient, far more efficient than decimal scaled types such as Java's BigDecimal. The price is that they are in a binary version of scientific notation which cannot represent most decimal fractions exactly.

Comment: what do you mean by all conversion from float to double are exact?? and how can i see the exact value??how can using any function print the exact value ??isn't there any format specifier for double?? how can i print the exact number that you wrote and see how they are convert ??

Comment: @SurajJain For every float, there is a double with exactly the same value. I used Java to do the printouts, because it has some features that make it easy. I also use an on-line [Decimal to Floating-Point Converter](http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/).

Comment: all conversion from float to double are exact because float is of only 4 byte and double is of  8 byte so double has more precision than float so it will not loose any precision and whereas when we convert double to float it looses precision because float  has less size than double so it will not be able to contain the precision. Am i right ??? or am i wrong somewhere that is how i understand that conversion between float to double is exact. Please correct me if i am wrong somewhere....

Comment: @SurajJain I've expanded on the float to double conversion question. I am not going to comment on C materials. My C expertise is out of date, and in any case book recommendations are off-topic for SO. I suggest some web searches for reviews.